# Converting characters to numeric in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame in which most of my variables are character and I would like to convert some of them into numeric.

I've tried to convert some of these variables to a numeric and I got the following error:

```
oport$Importe=as.numeric(oport$Importe)
```

> Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion "

the returned result is an NA column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0bPr.png)

Could anyone help out with these?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: PLease share some data. It means that you are trying to convert numerics that are not formatted correctly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I agree we lack data here. However, try this:

```
oport$Importe <- as.numeric(as.character(oport$Importe))
```

What happens here is that you first MAKE SURE that your column is a character column (you haven't provided data so we can't know for sure).

then it will be transformed to a numeric column - as it being a character column is a pre-existing condition in order for the column to be converted to numeric.

If this doesn't work, I recommend adding additional data to your original post. Good luck!